# regex + replace character between tags using Notepad++

Tags: php, regex, replace, simplexml

I think using regex to find/replace is my best option for this.. but I'll give an overview of what I'm trying to do in case there is some other advice/suggestions

1. I have a FLAT (static) .xml file
2. I am converting things over to use a database instead of loading this flat .xml file, (this will be your usual form interface/GUI, that submits to a MySQL database using PHP/PDO (no SQL injections here buddy!) ;)  (this is already working fine)
3. I am currently working on getting this 'back-log' of data from the flat .xml file into the database..

   a. I have tried to use `SQL LOAD XML INFILE`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775206/how-to-use-load-xml-infile-with-special-characters  but couldn't figure out how to parse/escape special character data...

   b. I have now moved onto `PHP/SimpleXML`, but am finding trouble again with special characters in some of the nodes/elements in the XML.  (could be single or double quotes, '&' sign, not sure.. its a 'description' field)

When I try to load the XML file.. I get an error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: xml_source.xml:142: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: BR line 142 and description in C:\wamp\www\xml_tests\simpleXML_test.php on line 4

If I find the xml node, and replace the apostrophe with `&apos;` it will parse and move onto the next node that has a special character that breaks it.

My gut instinct was try and find out how to use REGEX to search for any apostrophe (or any special character for that matter) between two tags....and do a replace before the data gets entered into the DB.

But maybe there is a better way to parse through PHP/SimpleXML.. however it seems I need to get rid of this before SimpleXML will even read the file?

```
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('xml_source.xml')){
    trigger_error('Error reading XML file', E_USER_ERROR);
}

foreach($xml->entry as $entry){
    echo 'Name: ' . $entry->name . '<br />';
    echo 'Date: ' . $entry->attributes()->date_entered . '<br />';
}
```

Simple test, but as mentioned I get the error above with the apostrophes still in there.

How can I use REGEX to search for a special character (single quote/apostrophe) that is between two `< tags > < /tags >`

Here is the REGEX I have tried for the SEARCH part..(I cant seem to nail down the replace portion it replaces the whole word with the apostrophe for some reason?)

Search: (Notepad++)

```
[?=<description>].'[?=</description>]
```

Replace:

```
\&apos;
```

example of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
    <entry submissionDate="2013-02-18">
        <fontName>String/Text</fontName>    
        <fontCreator>String/Text</fontCreator>
        <fontFormat>String/Text</fontFormat>
        <optimized>String/Text</optimized>
        <fontPrice>Nuumber/Int (with decimal)</fontPrice>
        <fontImage>String/Text</fontImage>
        <fontURL>Int</fontURL>
        <description>Don't can't lot's of 'single' quote/apostrophes and "double quotes" too</description>
        <piracyVid>String/Text</piracyVid>
        <demoLink>String/Text</demoLink>
    </entry>

    <entry submissionDate="2013-02-18">
        <fontName>String/Text</fontName>    
        <fontCreator>String/Text</fontCreator>
        <fontFormat>String/Text</fontFormat>
        <optimized>String/Text</optimized>
        <fontPrice>Nuumber/Int (with decimal)</fontPrice>
        <fontImage>String/Text</fontImage>
        <fontURL>Int</fontURL>
        <description>Don't can't lot's of 'single' quote/apostrophes and "double quotes" too</description>
        <piracyVid>String/Text</piracyVid>
        <demoLink>String/Text</demoLink>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your XML is simply invalid. Shouldn't you fix that problem? There's nothing wrong with simple apostrophes. Can you post an example of the XML file?

Comment: I agree with Phil regarding broken xml and requiring an example, as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping) specific characters need to be escaped. Are you able to go back a step and fix whatever is generating the xml file?

Comment: thanks for the replies.

Yes that is what I am trying to do, 'fix' the XML before parsing it with PHP/SimpleXML. (Hence the regex question for replacing the single quotes/apostrophes)

As mentioned this is a FLAT .xml file.  Open it up in any editor add a new node/element save)..

doesnt matter if I escape then or replace them..(I cant get the regex to work)

I'm not sure why this will help...but here is a snippet of the XML layout:

Comment: xml sample added to original post above (too long for comment)

Comment: my regex attempt only yields failed results:

can't
becomes
ca&apos;

    [<description>]'[</description>]
    &apos;

and several other attempts at searching (replacing seems to be the failure though)

Comment: anybody out there that can help with regex to find/replace one (1) specific character between two tags?

Comment: What is your concrete problem to just do so? Added you an example if it's just you're clueless.

Answer (score 0):

With SimpleXML it's as easy as:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//entry/description') as $node) {
    $node[0] = preg_replace('/"/u', '(say it sam: \0)', $node);
}

$xml->asXML('php://output');
```

Which gives with your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
    <entry submissionDate="2013-02-18">
        <fontName>String/Text</fontName>
        <fontCreator>String/Text</fontCreator>
        <fontFormat>String/Text</fontFormat>
        <optimized>String/Text</optimized>
        <fontPrice>Nuumber/Int (with decimal)</fontPrice>
        <fontImage>String/Text</fontImage>
        <fontURL>Int</fontURL>
        <description>Don't can't lot's of 'single' quote/apostrophes and (say it sam: ")double quotes(say it sam: ") too</description>
        <piracyVid>String/Text</piracyVid>
        <demoLink>String/Text</demoLink>
    </entry>

    <entry submissionDate="2013-02-18">
        <fontName>String/Text</fontName>
        <fontCreator>String/Text</fontCreator>
        <fontFormat>String/Text</fontFormat>
        <optimized>String/Text</optimized>
        <fontPrice>Nuumber/Int (with decimal)</fontPrice>
        <fontImage>String/Text</fontImage>
        <fontURL>Int</fontURL>
        <description>Don't can't lot's of 'single' quote/apostrophes and (say it sam: ")double quotes(say it sam: ") too</description>
        <piracyVid>String/Text</piracyVid>
        <demoLink>String/Text</demoLink>
    </entry>
</entries>
```